# Apache poi converter is not showing the table borders lines after converting

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, pdf-conversion

I am having an issue when using Apache POI to create a DOC file, then convert to PDF.

Using Apache POI to create a DOC file works well, it outputs a DOC with text, tables, imagery and shaded headers without problems. If I use IText to create the PDF this also works.

I am trying to reduce development and change time by creating a DOC then converting this to PDF so that I do not have two code bases to manage.

When I convert the DOC to PDF using Apache POI converter, I got the Style Error.

```
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting one Styles document part, but found 0
```

I add the style in the code. but then get this error:

I also get a null pointer exception relating to the headers, error below:
    ERROR CODE

```
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:70) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
 at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:38) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
 at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.AbstractXWPFConverter.convert(AbstractXWPFConverter.java:45) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
 at com.imviewer.report.DocxReportBuilder311CUSTOM.ConvertToPDF(DocxReportBuilder311CUSTOM.java:878) [classes/:na]
 at com.imviewer.report.DocxReportBuilder311CUSTOM.doInBackground(DocxReportBuilder311CUSTOM.java:833) [classes/:na]
 at com.imviewer.report.DocxReportBuilder311CUSTOM.doInBackground(DocxReportBuilder311CUSTOM.java:1) [classes/:na]
 at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
 at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.utils.XWPFTableUtil.getGridColList(XWPFTableUtil.java:183) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
 at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.utils.XWPFTableUtil.computeColWidths(XWPFTableUtil.java:116) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
 at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitTable(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:867) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
 at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitBodyElements(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:251) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
 at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.start(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:199) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
 at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:56) ~[org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
 ... 11 common frames omitted
```

Then I have tried manually converting the DOC to PDF using Apache POI in a separate piece of code the text is output and tables/imagery appear to be in the correct place but no table lines show (although the spacing appears correct). However, if I open the created DOC, remove the table formatting, then re-apply, then convert the DOC to PDF, the lines appear.

It seems that the lines which show in the DOC created by Apache POI will not convert or show in a PDF converted by Apache - but, if we manually add table formatting it does show.

Can anyone help please?

```
public static void ConvertToPDF(File docPath, File pdfPath) {
        try {
            InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(docPath);
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc);
            PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pdfPath);
            PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
            System.out.println("Completed");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The Library Version Im using is:
[image]

Comment: At the very least you're using an old version of the third party DOCX to PDF converter that builds on Apache POI - you can tell that from the package names used. What happens if you upgrade to the latest one?

Comment: Thank you for replay, i'm using the latest version of apache poi, kindly check the attached screen short

Comment: You're using an old version of the xdocreport converter plugin though, that's what you need to upgrade!

Answer (score -2):

Add in document ,
document.createStyles();

Comment: please add more details, as of now it looks more of a comment than an answer. Thanks!